# What does stringWithFormat:@"%@-1" mean?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, stringwithformat

I'm reading someone elses code and they are using %@-1 to format an integer. I can't find anything on Google since it ignores symbols. Anyone else had more experience at string formatting than me?

`[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-1", subnumber]`

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html):

> Each conversion specification is introduced by the '%' character, or by the character sequence "%n$", after which the following appear in sequence:
>
> - Zero or more flags (in any order), which modify the meaning of the conversion specification.
> - An optional minimum field width. If the converted value has fewer bytes than the field width, it shall be padded with spaces by default on the left; it shall be padded on the right if the left-adjustment flag ( '-' ), described below, is given to the field width. The field width takes the form of an asterisk ( '*' ), described below, or a decimal integer.
> - An optional precision that gives the minimum number of digits to appear for the d, i, o, u, x, and X conversion specifiers; the number of digits to appear after the radix character for the a, A, e, E, f, and F conversion specifiers; the maximum number of significant digits for the g and G conversion specifiers; or the maximum number of bytes to be printed from a string in the s [XSI] [Option Start]  and S [Option End]  conversion specifiers. The precision takes the form of a period ( '.' ) followed either by an asterisk ( '*' ), described below, or an optional decimal digit string, where a null digit string is treated as zero. If a precision appears with any other conversion specifier, the behavior is undefined.
> - An optional length modifier that specifies the size of the argument.
> - A conversion specifier character that indicates the type of conversion to be applied.

We're using a conversion of the first type, since there's no dollar sign in here. Note the words *in sequence* at the top of the above list. The `@` is a conversion specifier character (as mentioned [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html)), which indicates that we should access the value passed in as an `NSObject` and read its `description` property. Since we've already reached the last bullet point, the format code actually ends after the `@` symbol, and as @Kevin Ballard pointed out, the `-1` is parsed as literal text.

Answer (score 5):

That's just going to print "NUM-1" (where NUM is the number). To give an example, if the number is 5, that will print "5-1".

When using format strings, any modifiers to the format token must occur before the format type specifier. In this case, that means any modifiers to the `%@` token must occur between the `%` and the `@` (though I'm not sure if there are actually any modifiers that `%@` accepts).

Answer (score 3):

subnumber is probably object of class like NSNumber. Like we use %d for int, %f for float, %@ is place holder for a refrence. In that case

```
NSNumber *subnumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:5];
NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-1", subnumber]);
```

will print '5-1'

Comment: I would suggest not using a dynamically created string as the first argument to `NSLog()`. In fact, if I remember correctly the compiler warns against it.

Comment: The argument to `NSLog` is already a format string, so you should just write `NSLog(@"%@-1", subnumber);`